# Updated certain field of a document and do not effect the rest

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have below code.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: request.body.id }, record, {new:true})
  .exec((error, doc) => {
    if (error) return response.json(error);
    return response.json(doc);
  });
```

Above code when I enter all the fields such as name, email and password then it correctly update the `User Schema` however, when I provide name and email but not password then it again updates all the fields including the password to `null` value. But in second scenario I do not want to update the password because I am not providing the password so it should not change. How can I make it work as I intend?

**UPDATE**

I ended up using below method but for `save` password is required and it has a pre hook that which encrypts password before saving. That means password is necessary for this method.

```
User.findOne({ _id: request.body.id })
 .exec((error, user) => {
  if (error) return response.json(error);

  user.name = request.body.name;
  user.email = request.body.email;
  user.password = request.body.password;

  user.save();

  return response.json(user);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$set` for partial update as following:

```
Users.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: request.body.id },   // query
    {
        "$set": {                   // doc
            "name": req.body.name,
            "email": req.body.password
       }
    },
   { upsert: true, new: true },             // options
    function(err, doc){             // callback
        if (err){
            throw err;
        } else if(doc){
            console.log('Existing document updated successfully');
            console.log(doc);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: The problem is that this one is deprecated.

Comment: with upsert it still updates the password even if I do not provide.

Comment: and `$set` is also the same. I mean same issue as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with new **updateOne()**. You can do like this:

```
const updateObj = {
    "$set": {
        "name": req.body.name,
        "email": req.body.password
    }
};

const updateQuery = User.updateOne({
    _id: request.body.id
}, updateObj, {
    new: true
}).exec();

updateQuery
    .then((updateResponse) => {
        console.log("Record update successfully");
        response.status(200).json(updateResponse);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error while updating record: ", err);
        return response.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
```

You can read more on: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/

Hope this helps :)